# Jest v27 FSREQCALLBACK warning with FeathersJS NeDB services

Tags: jestjs, feathersjs

Since an upgrade to Jest v27 on my FeathersJS app, a bunch of warnings occurs at the end of the test suites:

```
Jest has detected the following 24 open handles potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  FSREQCALLBACK

       5 | export default (app: Application): NeDB<any> => {
       6 |   const dbPath = app.get('nedb');
    >  7 |   const Model = new NeDB({
         |                 ^
       8 |     filename: path.join(dbPath, 'billing-departments.db'),
       9 |     autoload: true,
      10 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous>.async.setImmediate (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:96:15)
      at node_modules/async/lib/async.js:696:21
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at _each (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
      at _insert (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:681:11)
      at Object.push (node_modules/async/lib/async.js:708:15)
      at Executor.Object.<anonymous>.Executor.push (node_modules/nedb/lib/executor.js:57:16)
      at Datastore.Object.<anonymous>.Datastore.loadDatabase (node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:88:17)
      at new Datastore (node_modules/nedb/lib/datastore.js:76:29)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.default (src/models/billing-departments.model.ts:7:17)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.exports.default (src/services/billing-departments/billing-departments.service.ts:8:12)
      at Function.configure (node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/application.js:59:8)
      at Function.Object.<anonymous>.exports.default (src/services/index.ts:28:7)
      at Function.configure (node_modules/@feathersjs/feathers/lib/application.js:59:8)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app.ts:50:4)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/services/sms.test.ts:1:1)
...
```

This warning is reported for each of my service test even freshly created by the cli.

It occurs with this kind of simple test:

```js
import app from '../../src/app';

describe('\'auth-sms\' service', () => {
  it('registered the service', () => {
    const service = app.service('auth-sms');
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How to solve this open handles problem properly?

Comment: Have you tried debugging using `detectopenhandles` flag.? Documentation : https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--detectopenhandles